# Nokogiri gem vs. opening by hand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, web-scraping, nokogiri

I can't get Nokogiri to return the same thing I see when I go to a page and "View Source". And for the life of me can't figure out why.

This is the page I am looking at:
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009NWFP5Q](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009NWFP5Q)

And as you can see it returns a shoe that's orange..and if I view the source and find the link I'm looking for by searching for "hiRes" twice, I get:
[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71b75uTtzDL.*UL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71b75uTtzDL._UL1500_.jpg)

However, if I run this code with Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'uri'

url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009NWFP5Q"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

pic = doc.css('div#imageBlock_feature_div script')[0]

puts pic
```

and look for the link in the same position I get this image:
[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81R97WG9nyL.*UL1500*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81R97WG9nyL._UL1500_.jpg)

which is a BLUE shoe!!! Arghhh..

Any idea why??

Comment: It's very common these days to have DHTML pages, where JavaScript, or CSS, modifies the content or display of the page. Browsers interpret and execute the JavaScript, and you'll see the finished result when you do a "show source". Tools like Nokogiri, and by extension, Mechanize, do *NOT* interpret JavaScript. Instead they see exactly what you'd see if you turn off JavaScript in the browser and load the page and view the source. I'd suspect this problem any time you can't see the same HTML in Nokogiri that the browser sees. You should look into using something from the Watir project.

Comment: Also, don't use `doc.css('div#imageBlock_feature_div script')[0]`. Instead use `doc.at('div#imageBlock_feature_div script')` or `doc.at_css('div#imageBlock_feature_div script')`.

Comment: Ok, that's great.. I'll check that out.. Yea because I was even searching for the item and then entering that URL and it still was picking up the default image on that page, which wasn't what I was looking for..

Comment: When working with HTML, it's always good to use `wget` or `curl` to retrieve the page and look at it in an editor. Then you know exactly what they're sending and can quickly find the dynamic modified/loaded sections.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the color being shown is somehow based on your session or dynamic attributes assigned to a cookie stored in your browser. Find a way to provide a URL that will return exactly what you are looking for. It may also be possible to provide a cookie using the http client code but that seems like a plan B.